# Java play framework add response headers for all requests

Tags: java, playframework

In my application based on REST API, I need to return for all results of all requests, a custom field in the Response Headers. Now I use this approach:

```
response().setHeader("custom-field",valuateSender());
return ok(response.addData(body));
```

In this way, however, I am forced to call the `result()` method in all my actions, I'm looking for a more general and more intelligent approach.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a ***Filter*** which will be global and applies to all of your routes.

then delegate the response and add your custom header before returning data to the client.

this could be a part of your filter:

```
public class AddCustomHeaderFilter extends Filter {

  @Override
  public CompletionStage<Result> apply(
      Function<Http.RequestHeader, CompletionStage<Result>> nextFilter,
      Http.RequestHeader requestHeader) {
    return nextFilter
        .apply(requestHeader)
        .thenApply(
            result -> {
              return result.withHeader("custom-key", "custom-data");
            });
  }
}
```

more info on Filters:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaHttpFilters